# Running thread with active screen

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnStart;
MyTask objMyTask;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnstart);
    btnStart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            objMyTask = new MyTask();
            objMyTask.execute();
        }
    });
}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Integer> {  
@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {...}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {...}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {...}
}}
```

`MyTask` generates values in time intervals. During executing this thread, the screen on my device is active, but I want this app run for a longer time, so it would be better, if the screen was not active during the whole executing - it would be power-consuming. Do you know some solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a service instead of an Activity with a AsyncTask:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html